# Automatically unfolding a record definition when accessor is used

Tags: isabelle

Assume I have a record type and a constant definition of this type, like:

```
record r =
  r_x :: int
  r_y :: int
  r_z :: int

definition "a ≡ ⦇r_x=1, r_y=2, r_z=3⦈"
```

Now I want to prove something about a, for example:

```
lemma "r_x a + r_y a = 3"
```

Currently, I am doing such proofs by defining simplification lemmas for the different accessors:

```
schematic_goal [simp]: "r_x a = ?x" by (simp add: a_def)
schematic_goal [simp]: "r_y a = ?x" by (simp add: a_def)
schematic_goal [simp]: "r_z a = ?x" by (simp add: a_def)
```

**My question is**: Can I somehow derive these lemmas automatically? Or is there a method to unfold definitions, when used with an accessor function?

I don't want to prove the original lemma by adding a_def, because I usually only want to unfold the uses of `a`, where an accessor is used.

I don't want to use an abbreviation, because then the simplifier would work on complicated subterms inside the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to automatically derive the selector theorems for user-defined records in Isabelle2016. If you have to do something like this for several definitions of the same record type, you can automate the derivation a bit as follows:

```
lemma r_sel:
  assumes "r ≡ ⦇r_x=x, r_y=y, r_z=z⦈"
  shows "r_x r = x" "r_y r = y" "r_z r = z"
using assms by(simp_all)

lemmas a_sel [simp] = r_sel[OF a_def]
```

The lemma `r_sel` is only needed once for each record type. Then, you get the instantiation (here `a_sel`) with one line. For record transformers (i.e., something like `f r = r(|r_x = foo|)`), you can prove a corresponding lemma `r_upd` and derive the instances for your transformers.

If you need even more automation (or flexibility), you will have to implement the derivation yourself in Isabelle/ML. In general, one could use the `Ctr_sugar` infrastructure to build such selector derivations, but the record package in its current form does not work well together with `Ctr_sugar`.